# Complex Groupby Pandas Operation to Replace For Loops and If Statements

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a complex group of a group problem I need help with.

I have names of drivers, each of who have driven several cars over time.  Each time they turn on the car and drive, I capture cycles and hours, which are transmitted remotely.

What I am trying to do is use grouping to see when the driver gets a new car. 
I'm using Car_Cycles and Car_Hours to monitor for a reset (new car).  The hours and cycles are tabulated for each driver in ascending sequence until there's a new car and reset.  I want to make each car a sequence, but logically can only recognize the car by a cycle/hour reset.

I used a for loop with if statements to do this on the dataframe, and the process time takes several hours.  I have several hundred thousand rows with each containing about 20 columns.

My data comes from sensors over a moderately reliable connection, so I want to filter by using the following criteria: A new group is only valid when both Car_Hours and Car_Cycles are less the previous group's last row for 2 consecutive rows.  Using both outputs and checking for two rows of change sufficiently filters all erroneous data.

If someone could show me how to quickly solve for Car_Group without using my cumbersome for loops and if statements, I would greatly appreciate it.

Also, for those how are very venturous, I added my original for loop below with if statements.  Note I did some other data analysis/tracking within each group to look at other behavior of the car.  If you dare look at that code and show me an efficient Pandas replacement, all the more kudos.

```
name  Car_Hours  Car_Cycles    Car_Group     DeltaH
jan   101         404              1            55
jan   102         405              1            55
jan   103         406              1            56
jan   104         410              1            55
jan   105         411              1            56
jan     0          10              2            55 
jan     1          12              2            58
jan     2          14              2            57
jan     3          20              2            59
jan     4          26              2            55
jan    10          36              2            56
jan    15          42              2            57
jan    27          56              2            57
jan   100          61              2            58 
jan   500          68              2            58
jan     2           4              3            56
jan     3          15              3            57
pete  190          21              1            54
pete  211          29              1            58
pete  212          38              1            55
pete  304          43              1            56
pete   14          20              2            57
pete   15          27              2            57 
pete   36          38              2            58
pete  103          47              2            55
mike 1500        2001              1            55
mike 1512        2006              1            59
mike 1513        2012              1            58  
mike 1515        2016              1            57
mike 1516        2020              1            55 
mike 1517        2024              1            57
..............

for i in range(len(file)):
    if i == 0:

        DeltaH_limit = 57

        car_thresholds = 0
        car_threshold_counts = 0
        car_threshold_counts = 0
        car_change_true = 0         
        car_change_index_loc = i

        total_person_thresholds = 0
        person_alert_count = 0
        person_car_count = 1
        person_car_change_count = 0

        total_fleet_thresholds = 0
        fleet_alert_count = 0
        fleet_car_count = 1
        fleet_car_change_count = 0

        if  float(file['Delta_H'][i]) >= DeltaH_limit:
            car_threshold_counts += 1
            car_thresholds += 1
            total_person_thresholds += 1
            total_fleet_thresholds += 1


    elif i == 1:
        if  float(file['Delta_H'][i]) >= DeltaH_limit:
            car_threshold_counts += 1
            car_thresholds += 1
            total_person_thresholds += 1
            total_fleet_thresholds += 1

    elif i > 1:
        if file['name'][i] == file['name'][i-1]: #is same person?
            if  float(file['Delta_H'][i]) >= DeltaH_limit:
                car_threshold_counts += 1
                car_thresholds += 1
                total_person_thresholds += 1
                total_fleet_thresholds += 1
            else:
                car_threshold_counts = 0
            if car_threshold_counts == 3:
                car_threshold_counts += 1
                person_alert_count += 1
                fleet_alert_count += 1

            #Car Change??  Compare cycles and hours to look for reset
            if i+1 < len(file):
                if file['name'][i] == file['name'][i+1] == file['name'][i-1]:
                    if int(file['Car_Cycles'][i]) < int(file['Car_Cycles'][i-1]) and int(file['Car_Hours'][i]) < int(file['Car_Hours'][i-1]):
                        if int(file['Car_Cycles'][i+1]) < int(file['Car_Cycles'][i-1]) and int(file['Car_Hours'][i]) < int(file['Car_Hours'][i-1]):

                            car_thresholds = 0
                            car_change_true = 1
                            car_threshold_counts = 0
                            car_threshold_counts = 0

                            old_pump_first_flight = car_change_index_loc
                            car_change_index_loc = i
                            old_pump_last_flight = i-1

                            person_car_count += 1
                            person_car_change_count += 1                                

                            fleet_car_count += 1
                            fleet_car_change_count += 1



                            print(i,  ' working hard!')

                        else:
                            car_change_true = 0
                    else:
                        car_change_true = 0
                else:
                    car_change_true = 0
            else:
                car_change_true = 0

        else: #new car
            car_thresholds = 0              
            car_threshold_counts = 0
            car_threshold_counts = 0
            car_change_index_loc = i                
            car_change_true = 0         

            total_person_thresholds = 0
            person_alert_count = 0
            person_car_count = 1
            person_car_change_count = 0


            if  float(file['Delta_H'][i]) >= DeltaH_limit:
                car_threshold_counts += 1
                car_thresholds += 1
                total_person_thresholds += 1
                total_fleet_thresholds += 1

    file.loc[i, 'car_thresholds'] = car_thresholds
    file.loc[i, 'car_threshold_counts'] = car_threshold_counts
    file.loc[i, 'car_threshold_counts'] = car_threshold_counts
    file.loc[i, 'car_change_true'] = car_change_true    
    file.loc[i, 'car_change_index_loc'] = car_change_index_loc  

    file.loc[i, 'total_person_thresholds'] = total_person_thresholds
    file.loc[i, 'person_alert_count'] = person_alert_count
    file.loc[i, 'person_car_count'] = person_car_count
    file.loc[i, 'person_car_change_count'] = person_car_change_count

    file.loc[i, 'Total_Fleet_Thresholds'] = total_fleet_thresholds
    file.loc[i, 'Fleet_Alert_Count'] = fleet_alert_count
    file.loc[i, 'fleet_car_count'] = fleet_car_count
    file.loc[i, 'fleet_car_change_count'] = fleet_car_change_count
```

Comment: How does the data arrive to you? Surely not as python dataframes. Maybe as csv, xml, txt, xlsx? If so, import into database, run a query to capture new cars, import final table into python df using [pandas.read_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html). Classic SQL subquery problem! Aside from this, always handle large volumes like 100K+ data in a relational database.

Comment: The data comes as a csv.  At this point I think the below answer solves this fairly efficiently using pandas, but once I get the opportunity, I will definitely try this with a relational database and see if it gets any easier.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, and all we need to do is reproduce Car_Group, we can take advantage of a few tricks:

```
def twolow(s):
    return (s < s.shift()) & (s.shift(-1) < s.shift())

new_hour = twolow(df["Car_Hours"])
new_cycle = twolow(df["Car_Cycles"])
new_name = df["name"] != df["name"].shift()
name_group = new_name.cumsum()
new_cargroup = new_name | (new_hour & new_cycle)
cargroup_without_reset = new_cargroup.cumsum()
cargroup = (cargroup_without_reset - 
            cargroup_without_reset.groupby(name_group).transform(min) + 1)
```

Trick #1: if you want to find out where a transition occurs, compare something to a shifted version of itself.

Trick #2: if you have a True where every new group begins, when you take the cumulative sum of that, you get a series where every group has an integer associated with it.

The above gives me

```
>>> cargroup.head(10)
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    2
6    2
7    2
8    2
9    2
dtype: int32
>>> (cargroup == df.Car_Group).all()
True
```

Comment: OK, I'm very anxious to use these tricks.  Quick question about the following line:  new_cargroup = n | (h & c)

Comment: Finishing above:  OK, I'm very anxious to use these tricks.  Quick question about the following line:  new_cargroup = n | (h & c).  Do you mean to say n (or) (h&c)  as would be done in Boolean logic?  Is n suppose to be 'name', h = 'Car_Hours', and c = 'Car_Cycles'?   Or perhaps you are just suggesting a groupby statement goes here?  Could you clarify and if possible provide an precise example?

Comment: @BenC.: ah, sorry -- changed variable names to be more descriptive.  It's meant to be `new_cargroup = new_name | (new_hour & new_cycle)` -- we have to use the bitwise operations in pandas because `and` and `or` don't handle vector arguments.

Comment: Well, I am amazed at how simple and effective the solution is.  I never realized Boolean operations could be so powerful in pandas.  Not only does this work beautifully, but it gives me a lot of capability to go much further with data analysis.  Thank you so much!!!